# AndroidStudioのWebViewでステータスコード

Tags: java

AndroidStudioでWebviewでステータスコードを取得するために参考サイトを見てコードを書いたのですがアプリが途中で落ちてしまいます。どうしたらアプリが落ちないようになるでしょうか？

参考
http://saki0n.blogspot.jp/2013/04/android-webview.html

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView textView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        //myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
            @Override
            public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
                if (!url.matches("https?://[\\w\\.\\-]+(/.*)?")) {
                    return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
                }
                HttpGet req = new HttpGet(url);
                DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String mimeType = null, encoding = null;
                byte[] data = null;
                try {
                    HttpResponse res = client.execute(req);
                    // ここでステータスコードを取得できるよ!
                    if (HttpStatus.SC_OK == res.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()) {
                        HttpEntity entity = res.getEntity();
                        Header mimeHeader = entity.getContentType();
                        textView.setText(res.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
                        if (null != mimeHeader) mimeType = mimeHeader.getValue();
                        Header encodingHeader = entity.getContentEncoding();
                        if (null != encodingHeader) encoding = encodingHeader.getValue();
                        data = EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    String msg = e.getMessage();
                    Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), (null != msg) ? msg : "");
                } finally {
                    req.abort();
                    client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
                }
                InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
                return new WebResourceResponse(mimeType, encoding, stream);
            }
        });
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");
    }
}
```

Comment: アプリが落ちるということはエラーが発生していると思いますので、発生しているエラーを追記して頂けますでしょうか？

Comment: 実機デバッグをしていまして実機で「○○は終了しました」みたいな感じで落ちてしまいます。

Comment: 説明不足みたいでしたすみません。例えば[ここ](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html?hl=ja)などを参考に、まずはAndroidのログを確認してください。エラーログが出力されていると思いますので、それを質問文に追記してください。

Answer (score 0):

関係のある部分だけ抜粋します。

```
byte[] data = null;
try {
    if (HttpStatus.SC_OK == res.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()) {
        data = EntityUtils.toByteArray(entity);
    }
}
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
```

なので statusCode 200 以外では data == null です。
エラーログがないのでココが原因かは特定できませんが参考になるかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます！確かに関係ある感じがします！少し話が進展しそうな気がします！ありがとうございます！